# Quais os tipos de perguntas devem estar presentes no SOpt?

Tags: debate

Geralmente quando tenho alguma dúvida / problema eu costumo pesquisar na documentação oficial da linguagem, framework e em outros sites (incluindo o SOen) antes de fazer uma pergunta no SOpt, daí a minha pergunta:
Isso é recomendável?

Pergunto porque quase sempre consigo resolver minhas duvidas/problemas que são de natureza simples e média (as vezes questões mais avançadas como construção e compilação de bibliotecas) antes de vir ao SOpt (apesar de ter mais perguntas do que respostas =D), logo muitas soluções para problemas simples estarão "ocultas" de usuários com menos experiencia. Por outro lado, devemos poluir o site com questões simples?

Comment: Tenho ideia de já ter visto esta pergunta por aqui, mas não encontro...

Comment: Não importa se a pergunta é simples. Se for clara, bem formulada, e puder ajudar mais gente, será bem-vinda no site.

Comment: Também acho que não importa se a pergunta é simples. Apenas tome cuidado para não efetivamente **poluir** o site. Minha sugestão é: pergunte se achar alguma informação útil e interessante que não seja óbvia ou fácil de achar em português. Lembre-se de que todo usuário deve fazer uma pesquisa mínima antes de perguntar, pelo menos para ver se já não foi perguntado antes aqui. Além disso, evite colocar muitas perguntas simples e artificiais, pois também não queremos ser uma documentação paralela. :)

Comment: Eu sei que vai parecer mentira, as vezes os outros leem algumas perguntas minhas e pensam ser duvidas de iniciantes, mas é que eu aprendi a dar um "ar" de "iniciante" nas questões e ao meu ver isto desperta mais o interesse das pessoas lerem, escritas pouco mais difíceis e longas tendem a levar a desistência. :) Ao menos parece que comigo funciona

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Na verdade já foi comprovado que longas discussões, formulário e informações desanimam as pessoas, por isso tem se a boa pratica de quebrar as informações e formulários em pedacinhos.

Comment: Sim isto eu sei, tanto que sempre solicito divisão "por tópico", só quero dizer que "parecer iniciante" faz as pessoas terem mais interesse, mas quando o texto é um pouco mais técnico parece que as pessoas desistem, apenas isto :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Interessante sua abordagem. Quanto a perguntas grandes ou complexas, além do tamanho, tem a questão de intimidar alguns usuários que não tem tanta confiança.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vejo sua pergunta sob 2 pontos de vista diferentes que, apesar de relacionados, *nem sempre* caminham de mãos dadas. Um visando o ganho pessoal, e o outro o ganho comunitário.

É um jeito meio abstrato de começar uma resposta, mas fazer o que? Só posso garantir que, apesar de ser possível escrever tratados, dissertações e teoremas sobre o assunto, eu não tenho vontade, nem inteligência, suficiente pra isso.

Sob o ponto de vista *pessoal*, você resolve os problemas da maneira que achar mais confortável e eficiente. Pessoalmente, eu sempre tive poucas perguntas nos sites da SE por detestar incomodar os outros. Não importa que, conscientemente, eu saiba que fazer uma pergunta não é um "incômodo"... É assim que eu me sinto. Então, assim como você, eu tendo a só fazer perguntas quando já esgotei toda e qualquer alternativa para resolver meu problema.

Há uma probabilidade razoável de que fazer a pergunta imediatamente fosse ser mais prático, e talvez render uma solução mais direta do que fuçar documentações e tópicos obscuros de 4 anos atrás. Apesar disso, como eu disse, **cada um sabe como prefere resolver seus problemas**. Dessa forma, de maneira individual, não há como julgar o que é recomendável ou não, para você ou para alguém que decide que o primeiro passo é fazer uma pergunta no SO (pt ou en).

Sob o ponto de vista *comunitário*, um recurso ou conteúdo úteis são sempre bem vindos e, por isso, vale a pena fazer perguntas mesmo quando se sabe a resposta ou há como conseguí-la de outra maneira. É uma atitude que requer esforço, mas que acrescenta muito à comunidade. Incentiva a participação, a criação de bons conteúdos, dá a oportunidade aos outros usuários de compartilharem o que sabem e ajuda quem precisar daquilo no futuro. Nesse aspecto, é altamente recomendável que qualquer pergunta seja feita aqui, mesmo que você tenha capacidade - ou disposição - de conseguir a resposta em outro lugar.

Então, quanto a ser recomendável fazer perguntas simples aqui... Isso é relativo. É um bom ato para a comunidade, mas ninguém é obrigado ou forçado a fazê-lo. Da mesma maneira, ninguém pode ser criticado por fazê-lo só porque "você não faria".

Além disso, discordo veementemente do termo "poluir" para tratar de perguntas simples. Perguntas *ruins* poluem um site. Perguntas *simples* ajudam. É uma distinção que nem sempre está bem clara, por diversos motivos. Alguns pertinentes ao site e outros pertinentes à área de tecnologia no geral.

Quando se avalia a **qualidade** de uma pergunta, sua **dificuldade** não deve ser um fator. Dificuldade é absolutamente relativa. Você pode ser tão boa programadora quanto a Grace Hopper, mas ainda vão existir perguntar básicas sobre coisas que você desconhece. E você pode escrever uma excelente pergunta sobre o assunto. Da mesma maneira, você pode fazer uma péssima pergunta sobre um assunto complicadíssimo.

Talvez haja uma correlação entre qualidade e dificuldade. Mas definitivamente não é uma relação de causalidade. Perguntas boas são bem escritas, claras, diretas. Elas podem ser sobre concatenação de strings, estruturas de laço, gerenciamento de memória, invalidação de cache, paralelismo ou teorias de autômatos.

Novamente: **dificuldade é diferente de qualidade**.

Comment: `Você pode ser tão boa programadora` correção sou Programador

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Usei o gênero feminino propositadamente. Não estava me referindo necessariamente a *você*. Falei no geral.

Comment: @Gabe esta resposta de simples tem pouco :D

Comment: @JorgeB. Pois é... E olha que eu cortei uma parte no final sobre a quem pertencem as perguntas e respostas no site. Mas achei melhor guardar pra próxima

Comment: as questões de ganho pessoal, eu não gosto e não concordo em mantê-las no site.. Acho que deveria ficar somente as questões de ganho comunitário. O site seria muito mais rico e menos poluído de lixo eletrônico.

Comment: @DanielOmine Não entendi... o que você considera questões de "ganho pessoal"?

Comment: exemplo, eu tenho um trabalho e não consigo fazer, é algo bem específico que só serve para mim, apenas o meu caso específico. Então eu venho aqui e pergunto, geralmente sem apresentar esforço algum em resolver, nem ao menos pesquisei no google. Fico apenas esperando algum tonto me dar uma resposta e fazer o meu rtrabalho.. rsrs .. entendeu? Não entendo qual valor esse tipo de questão agrega a comunidade.