# Muitas perguntas de baixa qualidade denigrem a imagem do StackOverflow em Português?

Tags: debate, perguntas, comportamento, comunidade

Desde que entrei no StackOverflow em Português, principalmente nas áreas em que tenho mais afinidade, tenho constatado muitas perguntas de baixa qualidade. Dá a impressão de preguiça por parte do perguntador, de nem sequer fazer uma breve pesquisa na web, e que para qualquer pequeno obstáculo que encontrar em seu projeto de tecnologia, irá postar uma pergunta. 
Isso, pessoalmente, desestimula, e me faz não ter vontade de ajudar.

Sei que não posso comparar a versão original e consolidada do SO, com a recente em Português. Mas ficam as perguntas:

- O próprio título;
- Caso positivo, o que a comunidade pode fazer para reverter esta situação?

Comment: Não diria que a versão em inglês é um exemplo de um repositório possuidor de apenas perguntas excelentes. Não saberia traçar uma proporção de perguntas ruins aqui e lá, mas certamente pelo nosso tamanho diria que é mais fácil para nós contornar a situação. Como fazer isso? Não faço ideia.

Comment: Meh, o site é feito pelos usuários, então... Dá para dizer que isso é um problema... Cultural. É o mesmo que o problema dos votos, as pessoas têm que querer votar, não dá para obrigar, assim como não dá para obrigar as pessoas a pesquisarem antes de postar uma pergunta.

Answer (score 16):

## Muitas perguntas de baixa qualidade denigrem a imagem do StackOverflow em Português?

Não, acho que elas só atestam o corrente, que o nível médio do programador que fala português é baixo mesmo.

## O que a comunidade pode fazer para reverter esta situação?

O que (acho que) sempre faz: usuários mais experientes ajudando usuários menos experientes, desde correções gramaticais nas perguntas e respostas, sugerindo leituras de como fazer boas perguntas e respostas, e principalmente, dando o exemplo aos demais.

Acho que é um problema geral de defasagem educacional. O site está aí para mudar isso.

Comment: Cultural também, acho que irá concordar. O famoso, querer "de mão beijada". Não é que eu acredite que todos devam sofrer para conseguir algo, mas muitas vezes vale demonstrar um pouco mais de esforço. (PS, +1)

Answer (score 11):

Perguntas de baixa qualidade não denigrem o SOpt, se comparar o SOpt com SOen então com certeza o SOen tem muitas perguntas ruins e isso denigre a imagem dele? não, quando você lembra do SO(pt|en) quais perguntas são lembradas? as ruins ou as boas?

Algo curioso que vejo no SOen é que usuários de diferentes paises/culturas acabam cometendo exatamente os mesmos erros que o pessoal do SOpt ou possuem as mesmas dúvidas.

Outro dia montei por brincadeira uma lista de situações que geralmente terminam em problemas(algumas eu vejo quase todo dia :P). Com certeza você ve os problemas da lista nos dois SOs

```
- Parsear html com regex.
- Abusar de colunas multivaloradas.
- Salvar data como varchar.
- Utilizar ponto flutuante para representar dinheiro.
- Fazer o side server gerar código client server. ex imprimir um js que redireciona no lugar da da função side server
- Usar exeção como fluxo de controle.
```

> Dá a impressão de preguiça por parte do perguntador, de nem sequer fazer uma breve pesquisa na web, e que para qualquer pequeno obstáculo que encontrar em seu projeto de tecnologia, irá postar uma pergunta. Isso, pessoalmente, desestimula, e me faz não ter vontade de ajudar.

Todos aqui são voluntários e possuem algum critério para responder ou **não** perguntas, isso é normal.

> o que a comunidade pode fazer para reverter esta situação?

- O primeiro passo é dar uma noção de como o site funciona pode ser pela tour ou falando que aqui não é fórum, ex: você edita a pergunta no lugar de criar uma publicação nova.
- Sugira melhorias na abordagem e ferramentas quando for adequado. Algumas vezes o usuário assistiu um video onde o cara programava no bloco de notas, não é muito óbvio notar um erro de sintaxe.
- Indique bons materias de apoio podem ser perguntas do SO ou mesmo a wiki da tecnologia/linguagem etc.
- Se possível na resposta ou vezes nos comentários explique **como identificar certos problemas.**

---

**Conclusão**

Se autor da pergunta tiver vontande de editar/comentar as publicações, explicar melhor o que deseja os itens acima vão ajudar bastante, do contrario nada pode ser feito pois ele é o maior interessado se ele não fizer nada, quem vai?

Comment: O último ponto é o mais complicado, Já me apareceram muitos utilizadores que por mais que eu explique que não deve ir por aquele caminho e que deve fazer debug, o que acontece muitas vezes é que esse utilizador não tem formação para perceber isso. Programa ao som da música. Eu costumo dizer que uma coisa é programar outra é bater código.

Comment: @JorgeB. igual [isso aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82604/como-pegar-mais-de-uma-categoria-do-banco-na-mesma-tabela#comment167518_82604) ?
 e 
[parte 2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82604/91)

Comment: Votar mais e menos sem dó também. Serve pra isso, pra filtrar conteúdo bom do ruim. Meses atrás, lembro de usuários bem participativos que quase não tinham -1 no perfil, p.ex., deu 501 votos, sendo 1 negativo. Na minha opinião, isso não ajuda o site.

Answer (score 10):

Bom eu sou novato aqui e já fiz perguntas mal elaboradas no começo, eu acredito que o pessoal até faz uma busca na web mas acaba ficando com dificuldades para implementar e acaba postando aqui.

Muitas das vezes o cara fica com preguiça e acaba fazendo uma pergunta mal elaborada, é muito difícil identificar a razão por que ele escreveu daquela forma.

Na minha opinião para reverter a situação  nestes casos você deve incentivar o perguntador a reestruturar a sua pergunta mas diga a ele até em que ponto ele não foi claro ou o que ele deve acrescentar, simplesmente dê atenção para ele de forma recetiva e acredito que ele irá ter o interesse de reformular sua pergunta.

Comment: A questão também é que a fonte da dúvida ser de baixa qualidade. É digamos um `;` faltando numa linha de código em Java. O post em si, pode estar extremamente bem formulado e formatado.

Comment: ai realmente complica kk, mas não tem como evitar isso não o jeito e você instruir o camarada por mais idiota que seja a pergunta o erro que cometeu   , acho legal o inglês em que eles sai metendo o negativo e um abraço kk

Answer (score 8):

Como desenvolvedor precisando de ajuda, meu nível de satisfação com o site será proporcional ao número de vezes em que encontrar uma questão que realmente me ajuda.

Não é incomum eu estar pesquisando em Inglês sobre um determinado assunto e cair em várias perguntas do SOen, antigas ou até recentes, algumas de muita má qualidade, sem uma boa resposta.

Portanto, por um lado, perguntas ruins afetam como o desenvolvedor que procura ajuda vê o site.

Por outro lado, esse cenário só acontece porque as perguntas continuam ali sem que ninguém faça nada.

Como os outros já comentaram, se nós tomarmos certas ações para melhorar a qualidade, conseguirmos tornar o site mais útil e mais amado com o passar do tempo.

Claro, infelizmente, existem casos complicados, como perguntas abandonadas pelo autor, mas nesses casos podemos ao menos mostrar que tentamos ajudar e, se for o caso, suspender a questão.

Também não podemos ficar transtornados por perguntas que ficam abertas. Não foi uma ou duas vezes que vi perguntas bem antigas serem respondidas.

Answer (score 7):

Não posso questionar se perguntas assim desestimulam, ou se deveriam desestimular. No final das contas, cada pessoa responde o que tiver interesse e segue a festa.

Mas me chamou atenção no seu post como você descreve as perguntas de baixa qualidade:

> Dá a impressão de preguiça por parte do perguntador, de nem sequer fazer uma breve pesquisa na web, e que para qualquer pequeno obstáculo que encontrar em seu projeto de tecnologia, irá postar uma pergunta.

Eu [já escrevi antes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3741/12) sobre a diferença entre **qualidade** e **dificuldade**. Não duvido que haja uma correlação entre ambas, é provável que seja o caso. Mas o que você descreveu - falta de esforço e pesquisa prévia - é indicativo maior de perguntas *fáceis*, não *de baixa qualidade*.

Não há uma linha clara entre o que é esforço de pesquisa suficiente, o que é um problema grande o suficiente, nem o que é necessário para demonstrar que você pesquisou o suficiente. E tentar traçar uma seria tentar enxugar gelo.
Um baita exercício de levianidade.

Como o @Cigano falou, aumentar a qualidade do site passa por ensinar, e dar bons exemplos, mais que rejeitar. O Stack Overflow é uma ferramenta totalmente nova para a grande maioria do público do site, e é importante dar a essas pessoas a chance de aprender a tirar o melhor proveito dela, da mesma maneira que os usuários anglófonos tiveram, 6 anos atrás.

O comentário do @Math é verdadeiro. A qualidade aparente do SOen não vem do nível alto das perguntas feitas lá no dia a dia. Se fosse esse o caso, não haveriam tantos posts no MSOen reclamando de baixa qualidade e novatos estragando o site (familiar?). A qualidade aparente vem do calhamaço de 10 milhões de perguntas, muitas delas excepcionais. Praticamente todo problema já vai ter sido perguntado, mais de uma vez, e recebido uma resposta excelente ao longo dos últimos 6 anos.

Claro que não é apenas uma questão de volume, assim como não é apenas uma questão de qualidade média maior. Não estou tentando simplificar um problema, mas sim ponderar que existem muito mais fatores que influenciam a utilidade e qualidade do site do que pode parecer.